# I am uploading a new aab file but its not uploaded

Tags: android, react-native, performance, apk, android-app-bundle

Your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key. Ensure that your App Bundle is signed with the correct signing key and try again. Your app bundle is expected to be signed with the certificate with fingerprint:
SHA1: 0F:2B:F7:05:A6:2E:D2:0D:D9:66:9D:05:7B:A2:ED:C5:B7:BF:E3:FF
but the certificate used to sign the app bundle that you uploaded has fingerprint:
SHA1: 68:36:E5:81:E9:E4:CC:39:9F:E4:C7:89:02:A2:AC:5E:79:D4:DC:4B

Comment: As per the error, your SHA1 is not matching with a previously uploaded version of your app.

Comment: if any command to update my key internally & 
I am not even getting the option to re-generate the release from where it will be enabled

Comment: Are you uploading a new application or updating your existing app on store?

Comment: sir update my existing code after google release key setup

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the same Keystore which you have used in the last uploaded build on the store even if the last build was uploaded for internal testing.